# sql multiple attribute join

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I'm creating a test database on medical practices. Here is a picture of my er diagram for reference. [ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCDid.png)

So basically my question is how to do joins properly. I'm trying to give a list of patients seen from a given practice (e.g practice id 1) but i also want to show the practice name and details. I also want to show a list of the patients and and gp's who work or have been to that practice (keep in mind i have only populated my tables with 10 rows of test data)

I have got so far

```
select patient.firstname, patient.surname
from patient
Join appointment on patient.patientid = appointment.patientid
where appointment.practiceid IN (1)
ORDER BY firstname;
```

`How would i also include the practice details and the gp details also who are associated with this practice. What's confusing me is how i add more select statements if they are not from the patient table. Any help would be great!

Comment: Good answers.  If your really want a given practice, (not a set of practices) it makes sense to change your where clause.  Use "where appointment.practiceid = 1".  It's faster and just good practice.  OTOH, if you really want a set of practices, just do your joins as suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I've included how to show the `Practice_Name` in your query, if you use the same join logic approach for each of the other queries you mention, you will work it out. I think that's a better way to learn rather than solving every question above in one answer.

```
SELECT    PR.Practice_Name, P.firstname, P.surname
FROM      patient AS P
            INNER JOIN appointment AS A ON P.patientid = A.patientid
            INNER JOIN Practice AS PR ON A.practiceid = PR.practiceid
WHERE     A.practiceid IN (1)
ORDER BY  P.firstname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add more `join` clauses:

```
SELECT   patient.firstname, patient.surname, practice.name, practice.address
FROM     patient
JOIN     appointment ON patient.patientid = appointment.patientid
JOIN     practice ON appointment.practiceid = practice.practiceid
WHERE    appointment.practiceid IN (1)
ORDER BY firstname;
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped!

Answer (score 0):

I like aliasing my SQL statements. Saves on typing.

```
SELECT p.firstname, p.surname, pr.Details
FROM patient p
JOIN appointment a ON p.patientid = a.patientid
JOIN Practice pr ON pr.PracticeId = a.PracticeId 
WHERE a.practiceid IN (1)
ORDER BY p.firstname;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this really helped!